# How do I optimize queries with PandaSQL?

Tags: python, pandasql

For business, I need to retrieve data using PandaSQL. I use around 4 queries in my code, and my base data size is 2,000,000.

I'm using following type of queries in my code. Note that the variables are dummies, but the syntax is the same.

```
import pandasql as pdsql    
str1="""select distinct class,year,section,student_name  from student_data where class=%d and year='%s'"""
        str2=str1%(class,year)
        pysql = lambda q: pdsql.sqldf(q, globals())
        df1 = pysql(str2)
```

Currently, the code takes five minutes and 30 seconds to execute. How could I make this run faster using PandaSQL in Python 3.x?

Comment: any suggestion from experts?

Comment: any suggestion @jezrael